# Java CSV Updater not saving updated TableModel

Tags: java, csv

This is the code I am using for the csv editor? It reads the csv file and shows it in the custom table and allows editing but I can't get saving and updating it to work.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;


public class T1Data {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

            String csvName = "effects";

            String datafile = path+"/files/logic/"+csvName+".csv";
            FileReader fin = new FileReader(datafile);
            DefaultTableModel m = createTableModel(fin, null);
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JTable table = new JTable(m);
            JScrollPane stable = new JScrollPane (table);
            stable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            stable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

            f.getContentPane().add(stable);
            f.setSize(1000, 600);
            f.setVisible(true);

            toExcel(m, new File(path+"/files/logic/"+csvName+".csv"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public static void toExcel(TableModel model, File file){
        try{
            FileWriter excel = new FileWriter(file);

            for(int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++){
                excel.write(model.getColumnName(i) + ",");
            }

            excel.write("\n");

            for(int i=0; i< model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for(int j=0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    excel.write(model.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+",");
                }
                excel.write("\n");
            }

            excel.close();

        }catch(IOException e){ System.out.println(e); }
    }



    public static DefaultTableModel createTableModel(Reader in, Vector<Object> headers) {
        DefaultTableModel model = null;
        Scanner s = null;

        try {
            Vector<Vector<Object>> rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
            s = new Scanner(in);

            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                rows.add(new Vector<Object>(Arrays.asList(s.nextLine().replace('"',' ') .split("\\s*,\\s*",-1))));
            }

            if (headers == null) {
                headers = rows.remove(0);
                model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headers);
            } else {
                model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headers);
            }

            return model;
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It will open up the effects.csv file and display it like this:
http://gyazo.com/fef8397deb3bcaa6dd93d03715f8262a.png

And then it allows me to edit the values but doesn't save it. I was hoping that when I close the window it would save but I can't get it to work. I will also be adding a button for save later as well.

How can I get the saving and updating to work?

Comment: I'd add a JButton, maybe to a JToolBar or add a JMenuItem to a JMenu on a JMenuBar which, when triggered, calls the toExcel method

Comment: But will that fix the edits not saving problem? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Yes, because Swing is like any other GUI, it's event driven. In your current code, when you call toExcel, nothing's actually been modified yet