# Java Fitting JPanel into Modal JDialog

Tags: java, swing, csv, jtable, jdialog

I have a class that returns a JPanel:

```
  public static JPanel program(String csvName) {

        JPanel f = new JPanel();

        try {

            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

            String datafile = path+"/files/logic/"+csvName+".csv";
            FileReader fin = new FileReader(datafile);
            DefaultTableModel m = createTableModel(fin, null);
            JTable table = new JTable(m);
            JScrollPane stable = new JScrollPane (table);
            stable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            stable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

            f.add(stable);

             f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(900,500));
             JFrame desktopFrame = new JFrame();
             desktopFrame.add(f);
             desktopFrame.setSize(900, 500);
             desktopFrame.setVisible(true);

            toExcel(m, new File(path+"/files/logic/"+csvName+".csv"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return f;

    }
```

And this is what is used to display the JPanel Modally.

```
String csv = "war";
JPanel f = T1Data.program(csv);

JDialog desktopFrame = new JDialog();
desktopFrame.add(f);
desktopFrame.setModal(true);
desktopFrame.setSize(900, 500);
desktopFrame.setVisible(true);
```

However the result I am getting has the JPanel centered and not fitting the JDialog.

It looks like this:
http://gyazo.com/4bc360e7d2c7cf7117a95d748d520838.png

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JPanel` is using a `FlowLayout`, if you change it to a `BorderLayout`, the scroll panel will be laid out so it fills the full container.

You should also consider using `JDialog#pack` over `setSize` as well

Comment: thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606331/java-csv-updater-not-saving-updated-tablemodel could you also check that question out for me? It's another problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

To make the panel fit the size of the dialog, you can either change the `LayoutManager` of the dialog, or ,since this should obviously be the only panel added to the dialog, simply set the panel as contentpane (`desktopFrame.setContentPane(f)` instead of `desktopFrame.add(f)`).